# eval at Assembly level

Tags: assembly, eval

I started studying the very basic Assembly language and I've learnt that the compiled code goes into a special segment named `Code Segment` which is (at least in modern architectures) a write-protected segment.

But a question pops out: in some programming languages (i.e.: *EcmaScript*, *Python*, etc.) there is the magic `eval()` function that takes a string, parses it and then executes it.

As the code is evaluated at runtime (then after the Code Segment is populated) and the Code Segment is write-protected, what kind of sorcery does it perfom?

I suppose it's related to JIT compilation but yet no clues on how it works at low level.

Comment: python is interpreted (unless using pypi, but even there you can call the interpreter dynamically). So `eval` just evaluates the expression using the built-in interpreter. This is not possible in assembly or compiled languages.

Comment: no, see my edit. interpreted codes are ... interpreted! the bytecode system allows to save time on the parsing, but that's the same thing: interpreted. JIT generates native code on-the-fly in a non-read only segment but you don't have easy access to this segment (like you could in C) so it's rather safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the example of python.

Python is interpreted (unless using pypi or JIT-capable engines, but even there you can call the interpreter dynamically). When running, the program has always access to the interpreter built-in the python executable, which is running at the time (the evaluation is part of the *runtime* which is consequent)

So `eval` just evaluates the expression using the built-in interpreter.

Since python means to be performant, your code is converted to bytecode when loading modules to save text-parsing time (Java does that at compile-time for instance), but the real machine instructions which are executed are contained in the `python` executable (which interprets bytecode and do appropriate actions) or loaded `.pyd` files which are DLLs.

JIT is just another optimization on top of the bytecode one: it generates native code on-the-fly in a memory segment but you don't have easy access to this segment (like you have in C with function addresses) so it would be very difficult to hack this code from inside a python program.

This is not possible (at least not easily) in assembly or compiled languages (C, C++, Ada...), not really because of write protection of code segment (which is not guaranteed) but merely because of the inability of the running program to assemble/compile code: it does *not* embed the compiler/assembler. The runtime, if it exists, is minimal and certainly does not contain a source-code evalulation.

The closest easiest thing would be to create a temporary file with your program, call the compiler/assembler on it from your program and execute it in a separate process or dynamically loading a DLL, but that's not trivial.

The other possible thing as Frank remarked would be to create a virtual machine within your program to evaluate the machine-code instructions like the real CPU would do (or high-level instructions like the compiler would do). Needless to say it is not trivial, but some already existing libraries do that (QEMU for instance), and even with existing material, it's far from easy to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please excuse me but low-level is still quite obscure to me.
Basically we have compiled bytecode (at runtime with Python, at compile-time with Java) which is an Assembler equivalent and which is executed via Pyton (or JVM as well).
By this way an user input eval code is compiled at runtime to a bytecode which is dynamically loaded (interpreded)?

Comment: @Fylax: Of course, there is nothing magical about those virtual machines. You merely need to implement the compiler yourself. Just implement the compiler and bytecode interpreter yourself, or generate machinecode directly and emit the the output into a memory block allocated with write and execution privileges. Of course for a non-trivial programming language doing this in assembly is a lot of tedious work, but you might a proof-of-concept for something along the lines of, say, a graphing calculator compiling functions for repeated evaluation easily enough.

Comment: Your answer above reads as though you can't write a dynamic interpreter in assembler? **Of course** you can as it is just a data driven and evaluated versus machine code generation and compile.

Comment: @FrankC. impossible for most mere mortals :) I have edited my post.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I got a picture on what's going on

Answer (score 3):

Answer from different point of view...

The non-writeable flag of "code segment" is just arrangement done by OS during loading of executable. There's nothing on HW level preventing OS to prepare writeable+executable page of memory too, it just become a convenient safety measure and bug prevention to run executables in write-protected memory page. And the creators of applications respect that and don't use self-modifiable code any more (was a common practice in early Assembly programming). (unless they allocate additional memory from OS exactly for this purpose, to write there and execute it after)

Also the whole "code segment" is high level abstraction, the CPU itself is not aware of something like that.

(x86) CPU has only current privileges level, and virtual memory map, so any memory address it does access, it will translate into physical memory address trough the virtual map definition while checking the privileges of that memory "page" (can-read / can-write) against requested operation.

In case the access is not valid, it will trap into error handler, which is usually OS provided.

Whether the application is loaded with code and data in separate memory pages, or even data sections have fine distinction between writeable and read-only, it's all up to OS and application loader to set it up by the means of the simple privilege/flag mechanics of memory mapping provided by CPU. If you have your own OS, you can as well map the whole memory in one big unprotected chunk with read+execute+write allowed for everyone.

Comment: It's also easy to JIT into a writeable page, and then ask the OS to change it to read+execute without write permission.  So even on a strict OS that refuses to ever allow W+X pages, you can still JIT.  But not self-modifying code that modifies itself on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not skinned in Python, but yes in embedded systems. In a PC, I suppose that the Operating System (Windows/Unix/Android/etc) is going to reserve via the MMU (Memory Management Unit) physical memory areas to every segment and assign them their access rights. To dynamically load an executable program to execute it after, as Python can do, it should be previosly declared a segment for this purpose with read/write/execute rights. Python should do it by default, but it should not be "Code Segment", as you are saying that it is read-only. That is, not all the "program code" goes to the same segment. 
In assembler code, for example, it is possible to fix where are going to be pre-located on piece of code/data declaring it on a "segment/section name". The linker will take the segments with the same name of the files contained on the project joining in a sequential mode those that have the same name and allocate them to the addresses fixed by the "linker directive file" (sometimes an ".ld" extension file).
The different compilers have name conventions for the segments (typical are "code", "data", "text", "bss", etc). Every one has typically their attributes for read/write/execution access rights.